# AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:xxxx

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, imagepicker

I get this error when picking a photo from image picker on a real device. I stumbled upon lots of similar questions but haven’t quite found anything regarding this error when accessing image picker on real device. There aren’t any network requests being fired in the app, it’s just a button which displays image picker when tapped.

```
2022-07-28 09:37:52.891102+0200 NameOfTheApp[6638:361667] [Picker] Showing picker unavailable UI (reason: still loading) with error: (null)
2022-07-28 09:37:53.548035+0200 NameOfTheApp[6638:361940] [AXRuntimeCommon] Unknown client: NameOfTheApp
2022-07-28 09:38:20.607892+0200 NameOfTheApp[6638:361923] [AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:6646 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001c5580a8c DE935F35-C84D-3E8D-BC40-E8D0D1D34197 + 326284
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001c5535d70 _AXGetPortFromCache + 704
    2   AXRuntime                           0x00000001c553769c AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 564
    3   UIKit                               0x000000021060c240 84364574-5373-346D-9593-93A1572D3983 + 934464
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103054c70 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001030567c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010305e8a4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 984
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010305f5e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 428
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010306c168 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 908
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000002102dc0bc _pthread_wqthread + 288
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000002102dbe5c start_wqthread + 8
)
2022-07-28 09:38:20.613683+0200 NameOfTheApp[6638:361923] [AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:6646 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001c5580a8c DE935F35-C84D-3E8D-BC40-E8D0D1D34197 + 326284
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001c5535d70 _AXGetPortFromCache + 704
    2   AXRuntime                           0x00000001c553769c AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 564
    3   UIKit                               0x000000021060c240 84364574-5373-346D-9593-93A1572D3983 + 934464
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103054c70 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001030567c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010305e8a4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 984
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010305f5e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 428
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010306c168 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 908
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000002102dc0bc _pthread_wqthread + 288
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000002102dbe5c start_wqthread + 8
)
2022-07-28 09:38:20.615705+0200 NameOfTheApp[6638:361923] [AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:6646 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001c5580a8c DE935F35-C84D-3E8D-BC40-E8D0D1D34197 + 326284
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001c5535d70 _AXGetPortFromCache + 704
    2   AXRuntime                           0x00000001c553769c AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 564
    3   UIKit                               0x000000021060c240 84364574-5373-346D-9593-93A1572D3983 + 934464
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103054c70 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001030567c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010305e8a4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 984
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010305f5e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 428
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010306c168 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 908
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000002102dc0bc _pthread_wqthread + 288
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000002102dbe5c start_wqthread + 8
)
```

I would highly appreciate anyone answering to this problem because I really don’t see a solution. Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? getting same error

Comment: unfortunately not, let me know if you find anything :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed my picker function like this with a dispatch and it works for me now

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            for result in results {
                
                result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: { (object, error) in

                    if let image = object as? UIImage {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.parent.pickerResult.append(image)

                        }
                    }
                })
            }
```

Comment: just tested my code again and for some reason it works fine now, also your’s working without bugs too, thank you